# Want to embed image in text line but have it lie lower than the text

Tags: html, css

I wish to embed an image in the middle of a line of text. I want to have the image sitting in the middle of the text like this: [image]

However when I try this it ends up like this: [image]

So I want the bottom of the image to be lower than the bottom of the text.

My code is as follows:

```
cticut <span><img src="images/CT.jpg" height="42" width="60"></span> ? Find
```

I've tried adding a margin-top and padding-top styling to the span but neither has any affect.

Comment: `position: relative; top: -10px;` Or `vertical-align` should work too.

Comment: @panther yup that worked thanks